# Trying to get a specific record from database on laravel8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a form in a page that basically is a login form. Now I want it to fetch the whole record of the username (including the `password`, `id`, etc from a database) just by using the username... is this possible?

This is my latest attempt but everytime I press the login button it always has an error... the last error is:

> "Trying to get property 'username' of non-object (View: E:\perkuliahan\pemrograman web lanjutan\perpustakaan\resources\views\halutama.blade.php)"

```
$cari = DB::select('select * from akuns where username = :username', ['username' => $vusername]);

return view('halutama')->with('cari', $cari);
```

On the view page I used this to get the data:

```
{{$cari->username}} {{$cari->id}}
```

Comment: I would guess that `$cari` is an array or collection of objects, not a single object. But you can use `Log::info($cari);` or `dd($cari);` inside of your controller to verify.

Comment: Try using the syntax suggested in the Laravel manual - `$user = DB::table('akuns')->where('name', $username)->first();` at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table

Answer (score 0):

If it says `"Trying to get property 'username' of non-object` it probably means that the query returns a non object.

Check [Laravel Query Builder Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) to see if the query is correct.

I would write it like this:

```
$cari = DB::table('akuns')->where('username', $vusername)->get();
```

Remember to use the `->get()` function.

Also as [@anyber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber) noted, it might be that the query returns an `array` instead of an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it better

```
$cari = DB::table('akuns')->select('*')->where('username', $vusername)->first();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could detail how OP could 'do it better', some documentation links and/or a description of how your query works would help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a raw query ? If you are using Laravel, with such a simple query, then you have to use Eloquent... Do not try to reinvent the wheel or do crazy stuff without looking at the documentation...

Your code should be like this (assuming you have created a model... but I doubt it):

```php
$cari = Akun::where('username', $vusername)->first();

return view('halutama')->with('cari', $cari);
```